# spree helpers in main_app and current_page for subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am using spree in my app and in my application_controller.rb I have this:

```
# These will allow use of spree helpers in main_app
include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers
helper Spree::BaseHelper

# Required to reset main_app to use its application.html.erb instead of spree's
layout "application"
```

I needed to be able to use Spree's helpers in my main_app like link_to_cart and such, and noticed that include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers is causing my main_app to use spree's spree_application.html.erb vs my application.html.erb so I forced my application to use its only layout after, but this is causing spree to use my main_app application.html.erb. So I'm kind of in a loop right now. How do I get my main_app to use its layout and spree to use its own layout?

Also I need to conditionally load some things on the spree views. Is there something like current_page?() that will be true for an entire subdirectory. For instance is there a helper that would be true for current_page?(/shop) for anything matching http://example.com/shop/product/cool-shirt? Match anything /shop/* ?

Comment: What does this controller inherit from? Also this kind of seems to be two questions in one.

Comment: Well I figured out if I changed my application_controller.rb to include instead this: `include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Auth
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Store
  helper Spree::BaseHelper
  helper Spree::StoreHelper` then spree and the main_app will both render their own application.html.erb files

Comment: @Chris I have a similar problem. I added Spree to an existing app and mounted it to ```mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/shop'``` hoping to just link there as needed. Unfortunately Spree dominates the whole app forcing its own application layout and loading Spree::Users and Orders. Did you figure out how to stop this from happening? I tried adding those helpers, no change.

Comment: Got it, I also had ```include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Common``` which sends all requests through ```app/views/spree/layouts/application.html.erb``` even if they aren't Spree controllers or actions. Pulled that out and it acted as expected.